# Kotlin annotations defined in tests not present in reflection info in integration tests

Tags: kotlin, gradle

We have a fairly standard Kotlin DSL Gradle build. We've added an integrationTest sourceSet and task:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    application
}

sourceSets {
    create("integrationTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.get().output
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.get().output
        resources.srcDir(sourceSets.test.get().resources.srcDirs)
    }
}

val integrationTest = task<Test>("integrationTest") {
    description = "Runs the integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
    mustRunAfter(tasks.test)
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Classes in `src/integrationTest/kotlin` can use classes from `src/test/kotlin` just fine, but annotations defined in `src/test/kotlin` do not show up in reflection data for classes in `src/integrationTest/kotlin`. When used on classes in `src/test/kotlin`, the annotations are present in reflection data as expected.

The annotations are very simple:

```
@Target(FUNCTION, CLASS)
// NB: Default Retention is RUNTIME (Annotation is stored in binary output and visible for reflection)
annotation class SystemProperty(val key: String, val value: String)

// Kotlin does not yet support repeatable annotations https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12794
@Target(FUNCTION, CLASS)
annotation class SystemProperties(vararg val systemProperties: SystemProperty)
```

This is how the annotations are used, in a JUnit 5 Extension:

```kotlin
class SystemPropertyExtension : BeforeAllCallback {
    override fun beforeAll(extensionContext: ExtensionContext) {
        val clazz = extensionContext.requiredTestClass
        clazz.getAnnotation(SystemProperty::class.java)?.let {
            System.setProperty(it.key, it.value)
        }
        clazz.getAnnotation(SystemProperties::class.java)?.let {
            it.systemProperties.forEach { prop -> System.setProperty(prop.key, prop.value) }
        }
    }
}
```

And typical use on the test itself:

```kotlin
@SystemProperty(key = "aws.s3.endpoint", value = "http://localstack:4566")
@ExtendWith(SystemPropertyExtension::class)
class SomeIntegrationTest {
    //
}
```

Setting breakpoints while running tests shows `System.setProperty(it.key, it.value)` getting called. However while debugging integration tests, the breakpoint is not hit.

Any ideas on what might be wrong/missing here?

We could add a "testing" module to the project and export the test-jar, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: So `BeforeAllCallback` isn't called?

Comment: No, it is called, but the annotation isn't found. Of course writing up this question helped me find it. The annotation was actually on the integration test base class, so the annotations needed to be meta-annotated with @Inherited.

Answer (score 0):

The annotations were simply missing @Inherited. They were found on classes, but without @Inherited, they weren't found via superclass.